# Should we allow questions such as "what will happen in the future"?

Tags: discussion

Here's a borderline? one:
[What is the expected Ether issuance schedule after transition to PoS?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/644/what-is-the-expected-ether-issuance-schedule-after-transition-to-pos)

Do we have a guideline of what's on-topic and off-topic regarding future releases of Ethereum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, **yes**. Answers like "there is no plan or roadmap yet" are totally valid in my eyes. And asking about the Ether issuance after switching to PoS is a hot, relevant topic.

It is possible that currently the answer is not really satisfying. But as soon as there are announcement by the ethereum developers for example, it could be updated and therefore be a good source of information for people researching on that subject.

In general, *what will happen in the future* questions have to be of both **high quality** and **high relevance**.

If they are speculative or if there is the risk to unleash a discussion, they should be marked off-topic.